# What is causing my SQL Select statement to have duplicate results?

Tags: sql, jdbc

```
SELECT orders.order_id, customers.customer_address, employees.employee_name 
FROM ((orders
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.delivery_area  = customers.customer_areacode)
INNER JOIN employees ON orders.delivery_area =  employees.delivery_area)
WHERE orders.delivery_area  = 62442;
```

Is getting me the following results

```
48  45 E Liberty St     Art
52  45 E Liberty St     Art
48  2881 Lewis Rd       Art
52  2881 Lewis Rd       Art
```

There are only two records that match this criteria and it displays 4. and if I run this same query with criteria matching one record it only shows one record. This is the weirdest thing to me! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share you table schema? sample data also

Comment: (1) Please tag your question with the database that you are using (2) Your query is incomplete, it is missing a `select` clause (3) Please show us sample data for the 3 tables involved, the corresponding results, and the results that you want to get (all as tabular text)

Comment: replicated `delivery area` and `customer area code` in each table

Comment: I think there should be a link between the orders and the customers. Maybe a join betwen the two via the customer_id. Because if two customers have the same area_code, the line will be duplicated where as adding the customer who made the offer will filter that. The same argument can be made with the employee who filled the order and the order table via the employee_id.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I think you are right, I removed delivery_area and joined them with a different field and it seems to have solved the problem. Will post the full solution once I test it. Thanks for sending me on the path!